# Use matching sub-pattern of each line

Tags: regex, sed

I have the following text file:

```
(ABC)
(DEF)
(GHI)
...
```

I want to use `sed` to change it to:

```
(ABCABC)
(DEFDEF)
(GHIGHI)
...
```

So I'm trying to match a sub-pattern of each line and access the variable in the replace pattern.

Obviously my failed attempt `sed 's/(.*)/&&/' file.txt` duplicates the whole line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use:

```sh
sed -E 's/\(([^)]+)\)/(\1\1)/g' file

(ABCABC)
(DEFDEF)
(GHIGHI)
```

**Details:**

- `-E`: Enable extended regex mode
- `\(`: Match a literal `(`
- `([^)]+)`: Match 1+ of any character that is not `)` and capture in group #1
- `\)`: Match a literal `)`
- `\1\1`: `\1` is back-reference of group #1 and by using `\1\1` we get repeat of matched group #1

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed -E 's/[^()]+/&&/' file
(ABCABC)
(DEFDEF)
(GHIGHI)
```

or if your sed doesn't have a `-E` argument to enable EREs then in any POSIX sed:

```
$ sed 's/[^()]\{1,\}/&&/' file
(ABCABC)
(DEFDEF)
(GHIGHI)
```

or in any sed:

```
$ sed 's/[^()][^()]*/&&/' file
(ABCABC)
(DEFDEF)
(GHIGHI)
```

If that's not all you need then edit your question to provide more truly representative sample input/output that includes cases for which this doesn't work.